# Striking through text when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, css, express, dom, ejs

I'm trying to make a To-Do list app using express and EJS as middleware. It's supposed to have a list of tasks with a checkbox beside every task that has been added. When the task is done you can check the checkbox and the text will get striked through signifying the completion of the task. I used adding javascript at the end of my .ejs file but there's some problem with it and its not working

here is the EJS code snippet

```
<% for(var i = listItems2.length -1; i >= 0; i--){ %>
                    <div class="flex">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="checker" id="checkbox_id" class="h-7 w-7 m-3 flex-shrink-0">
                      <p name="para" class="text-[32px] font-[200]"><%= listItems2[i] %></p>
                    </div>
<% } %>
```

and the javascript code

```
<script>
  var boxes = document.getElementsByName("checker");
  var paras = document.getElementsByName("para");
  function updateStyle() {
  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    if (boxes[i].checked) {
      paras[i].style.webkitTextStroke = "1px black"; 
      paras[i].style.textStroke = "1px black";       
    } else {
      paras[i].style.webkitTextStroke = "none";      
      paras[i].style.textStroke = "none";
    }
  }
}


for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  boxes[i].addEventListener("change", updateStyle);
}
</script>
```

Comment: What's `boxes` and what's `paras`? Are those defined anywhere?

Comment: I Apologise. I was kinda sleepy when i posted this. Edited the code, can you please now have a look? although someone already posted a solution using css but i was thinking maybe if theres a way of achieving the same result using DOM?

Answer (score 1):

Add a class or style the label to give it strike through styles when the checkbox is checked.

Use `::before` and `::after` content element to provide context that the item is stricken text.

```css
label {
  color: black;
}

#todo {
  accent-color: #777
}

#todo:checked+label {
  color: #777;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  &::before,
  &::after {
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(100%);
    clip-path: inset(100%);
    clip: rect 1px, 1px, 1px, 1px;
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 1px;
  }
  &::before {
    content: "[start of stricken text]";
  }
  &::after {
    content: "[end of stricken text]";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="todo">
<label for="todo">Todo Item</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the label around the checkbok (preventing the need for the for attribute and id - but you can leave those in if you want... and then put the label text in a span and use  the :checked pseudo selector  and direct sibling combinator to get the strike-trhough via css
I have set one item to checked to show the effect and you CAN add another span with the  ::before and ::after stylign on it to get a styled checkbox isf the bowser default stylngi is not to your liking.

```css
label {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px
}


input:checked+span {
  color: #777;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span>Todo Item</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>Todo Item 2</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>Todo Item 3</span>
</label>
```